# How can I get Spacy to stop splitting both hyphenated numbers and words into separate tokens?

Tags: python, regex, tokenize, spacy

Thanks for looking.  I am using spaCy to perform Named Entity Recognition on a block of text, and I am having a peculiar problem I can't seem to overcome.  Here is a sample code:

```py
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

doc = nlp('The Indo-European Caucus won the all-male election 58-32.')
```

This results in the following:

```
['The', 'Indo', '-', 'European', 'Caucus', 'won', 'the', 'all', '-', 'male', 'election', ',', '58', '-', '32', '.']
```

My problems is that I need those words and numbers that contain hyphens to come through as single tokens.  I followed the examples given at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55241927/spacy-intra-word-hyphens-how-to-treat-them-one-word) by using the following code:

```py
inf = list(nlp.Defaults.infixes)
inf = [x for x in inf if '-|–|—|--|---|——|~' not in x] # remove the hyphen-between-letters pattern from infix patterns
infix_re = compile_infix_regex(tuple(inf))

def custom_tokenizer(nlp):
    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, prefix_search=nlp.tokenizer.prefix_search,
                                suffix_search=nlp.tokenizer.suffix_search,
                                infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer,
                                token_match=nlp.tokenizer.token_match,
                                rules=nlp.Defaults.tokenizer_exceptions)

nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)
```

That helped with the alphabetic characters, and I got this:

```
['The', 'Indo-European', 'Caucus', 'won', 'the', 'all-male', 'election', ',', '58', '-', '32', '.']
```

That was much better, but the `'58-32'` was still split into separate tokens.  I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58175591/spacy-entity-rule-doesnt-work-for-cardinal-social-security-number) and got the reverse effect:

```
['The', 'Indo', '-', 'European', 'Caucus', 'won', 'the', 'all', '-', 'male', 'election', ',' '58-32', '.']
```

How can I alter the tokenizer to give me the correct results in both circumstances?

Comment: You removed the support for intraword hyphens (that is, hyphens between letters), but not between digits.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was the case, but I don't have the Python skills to combine those requirements.  I'm trying out your solution below; I should know in about 15 minutes if it works.  I'm glad you responded; your solutions to other spaCy questions have been helpful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may combine the two solutions:

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
from spacy.util import compile_infix_regex

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def custom_tokenizer(nlp):
    inf = list(nlp.Defaults.infixes)               # Default infixes
    inf.remove(r"(?<=[0-9])[+\-\*^](?=[0-9-])")    # Remove the generic op between numbers or between a number and a -
    inf = tuple(inf)                               # Convert inf to tuple
    infixes = inf + tuple([r"(?<=[0-9])[+*^](?=[0-9-])", r"(?<=[0-9])-(?=-)"])  # Add the removed rule after subtracting (?<=[0-9])-(?=[0-9]) pattern
    infixes = [x for x in infixes if '-|–|—|--|---|——|~' not in x] # Remove - between letters rule
    infix_re = compile_infix_regex(infixes)

    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, prefix_search=nlp.tokenizer.prefix_search,
                                suffix_search=nlp.tokenizer.suffix_search,
                                infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer,
                                token_match=nlp.tokenizer.token_match,
                                rules=nlp.Defaults.tokenizer_exceptions)

nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)
doc = nlp('The Indo-European Caucus won the all-male election 58-32.')
print([token.text for token in doc])
```

Output:

```
['The', 'Indo-European', 'Caucus', 'won', 'the', 'all-male', 'election', '58-32', '.']
```